# How to find length of a string array?

Tags: java

I am having a problem with the following lines where `car` is a `String` array which has not been initialized/has no elements.

```
String car [];
System.out.println(car.length);
```

What is a possible solution?

Comment: The solution probably depends on your problem. Care to tell us what it is?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Since `car` has not been initialized, it has no length, its value is `null`. However, the compiler won't even allow you to compile that code **as is**, throwing the following error: *variable car might not have been initialized*.

You need to initialize it first, and then you can use `.length`:

```
String car[] = new String[] { "BMW", "Bentley" };
System.out.println(car.length);
```

If you need to initialize an empty array, you can use the following:

```
String car[] = new String[] { }; // or simply String car[] = { };
System.out.println(car.length);
```

If you need to initialize it with a specific size, in order to fill certain positions, you can use the following:

```
String car[] = new String[3]; // initialize a String[] with length 3
System.out.println(car.length); // 3
car[0] = "BMW";
System.out.println(car.length); // 3
```

However, I'd recommend that you use a `List` instead, if you intend to add elements to it:

```
List<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println(cars.size()); // 0
cars.add("BMW");
System.out.println(cars.size()); // 1
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting lists, which are almost always a more suitable *interface* to work to than arrays.

Comment: Your first statement "Since car has not been initialized, it has no length, its value is null" is wrong. Since car has not been initialized, the code won't even compile. Referencing a potentially uninitialized variable is a compile time error.

Comment: You are right, `javac` indeed throws that error. I've edited my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 5):

Well, in this case the `car` variable will be `null`, so dereferencing it (as you do when you access `car.length`) will throw a `NullPointerException`.

In fact, you can't access that variable *at all* until some value has definitely been assigned to it - otherwise the compiler will complain that "variable car might not have been initialized".

What is it you're trying to do here (it's not clear to me exactly what "solution" you're looking for)?

Comment: well this comes as a part of the dynamic web project, where am not sure whether any value will be stored in the array or not!! And then i want to check whether my array has anything in it or not...

Answer (score 3):

```
String car [];
```

is a reference to an array of String-s. You can't see a length because there is no array there!

Answer (score 3):

This won't work. You first have to initialize the array. So far, you only have a String[] reference, pointing to `null`.

When you try to read the length member, what you actually do is `null.length`, which results in a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't initialized `car` yet so it has no existence in JVM(Java Virtual Machine) so you have to initialize it first.

For instance :

```
car = new String{"Porsche","Lamborghini"};
```

Now your code will run fine.

**INPUT:**

```
String car [];
car = new String{"Porsche","Lamborghini"};
System.out.println(car.length);
```

**OUTPUT:**

2

Answer (score 2):

As all the above answers have suggested it will throw a NullPointerException.

Please initialise it with some value(s) and then you can use the length property correctly. For example:

```
String[] str = { "plastic", "paper", "use", "throw" };
System.out.println("Length is:::" + str.length);
```

The array 'str' is now defined, and so it's length also has a defined value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

```
String[] car = new String[10];
int size = car.length;
```

Comment: wazzy: wat if the size of array is not known before hand?

Comment: Then an array may not be your best choice.  Look at a list as @Joao recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, we declare a String of arrays (eg. car) as

```
String []car;
String car[];
```

We create the array using new  operator and by specifying its type:-

```
String []car=new String[];
String car[]=new String[];
```

This assigns a reference, to an array of Strings, to car.
You can also create the array by initializing it:-

```
String []car={"Sedan","SUV","Hatchback","Convertible"};
```

Since you haven't initialized an array and you're trying to access it, a *NullPointerException* is thrown.