# How to display element count in an Array?

Tags: java

I'm trying to display the number of elements in an Array that I have made. It is a regular Array with a string as the data type. If it is possible to display the total number of elements in an Array, will the code be similar to an ArrayList's?

```
    String[] list = new String[14];
    list = new String[] {"Bob", "Sal", "Jimmy" ,"John"};


    list = insert(list, "Joe", 0);
    list = insert(list, "Manny", list.length);
    list = insert(list, "Joey", list.length/2);



    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));

}

public static String[] insert(String[] original, String value, int k) {
    String[] copy = new String[original.length + 1];


    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = original[i];
    }


    copy[k] = value;


    for(int i=k; i<original.length; i++)
    {
        copy[i+1] = original[i];
    }


    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Total number of elements in an Array: `array.length`

Comment: What is the point of creating an array of 14 elements, just to throw it away and replace it with an array of 4 elements in the next line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find length of a string array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862092/how-to-find-length-of-a-string-array)

Comment: @Andreas It was part of the assignment to demonstrate that you know how to increase the size of an array

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the best Array type to use is a List or ArrayList for inserting elements into that array by way of the [**ArrayList.add(index, valueToAdd)**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_add_index.htm) method. It of course can be done with basic Arrays but a little more work on your part is required to carry out the task as you have already noticed. One possible way might be like this:

```
public static String[] insertStringArrayElement(String[] original, String value, int atIndex) {
    // Make sure the supplied index (k) is within bounds
    if (atIndex < 0 || atIndex > original.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\ninsertArrayElement() Method Error! "
                                    + "The supplied index value is invalid (" 
                                    + atIndex + ")!\n");
    }

    String[] tmp = new String[original.length + 1];
    int elementCount = 0;   //Counter to track original elements.
    for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        // Are where we want to insert a new elemental value?
        if (i == atIndex) {
            tmp[i] = value; // Insert the new value.
            i++;            //Increment i so to add the orininal element.
            // Make sure we don't go out of bounds.
            if (i < original.length) {
                tmp[i] =  original[elementCount]; // Add original element.
            }
        }
        // No we're not...
        else {
            tmp[i] = original[elementCount]; // Add original element.
        }
        elementCount++; // Increment counter for original element tracking.
    }
    return tmp; // Return our new Array.
}
```

As Andreas has so kindly pointed out, in your original posted code you had declared the **list** String Array and initialized it to contain 14 elements but in the very next line you reinitialize this array to contain only 4 elements. The first initialization is a waste of oxygen, time, memory, effort, etc since you could have just declared and initialized the Array like this:

```
String[] list = new String[] {"Bob", "Sal", "Jimmy" ,"John"};
```

or better yet:

```
String[] list = {"Bob", "Sal", "Jimmy" ,"John"};
```

Just something to remember.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an ArrayList if possible, since it would be a lot easier with the method `size()`. If you have to use an array, since the array is already sized, you could check with a for loop, which slot of the array is != to null and add them to a counter.

Comment: Nothing in the question mentions not counting null values, and the array in the example has no nulls *(ignoring the garbage 14 element array that's immediately thrown away)*.