# array.size() cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I got this code

```
public void displayText(){
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(chosenArrayName, "array", getPackageName());
    String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(resourceId);
    int arraySize = array.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        textView.append(array[i]);}

    }
```

From
[Android how to print a array in text view or anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668041/android-how-to-print-a-array-in-text-view-or-anything)

The arraySize = array.**size()**; cannot be resolved.
Anyone help me to point out why?

Comment: the arrays have a `.length` property in  Java

Comment: `resourceId` is `int` type. how come you expect an integer to have a `size()` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find length of a string array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862092/how-to-find-length-of-a-string-array)

Comment: @kcg Please check again the code. I have edited it

Comment: @NagyVilmos I understand, but why is it using .size in the answer of this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668041/android-how-to-print-a-array-in-text-view-or-anything

Comment: @Anthony IMHO that's just a wrong answer.

Comment: your array is a int array => int[]  so you must use .length property.
if it was a Collection, then you could use size() method.

Comment: @NagyVilmos Thanks Nagy, Can anyone just delete/downvote/reanswer the question since i had search the forum and it is appearing a lot in the search, but is a wrong answer.

Comment: @Anthony I've already commented there that answer could be misleading, or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call size() method in int. Try this :

```
public void displayText(){
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(chosenArrayName, "array", getPackageName());
    String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(resourceId);
    int arraySize = array.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        textView.append(array[i]);}
}
```

Comment: Just change the size() to length. will solve the problem, Thanks
I don't know why they downvote too. But thanks for your answer